# How to specify the number of peaks in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab

So far I found 4 ways to find peaks in Python, however none of them can specify the number of peaks like Matlab does. Can someone provide some insight?

```
import scipy.signal as sg
import numpy as np

# Method 1
sg.find_peaks_cwt(vector, np.arange(1,4),max_distances=np.arange(1, 4)*2)

# Method 2
sg.argrelextrema(np.array(vector),comparator=np.greater,order=2)

# Method 3
sg.find_peaks(vector, height=7, distance=2.1)

# Method 4
detect_peaks.detect_peaks(vector, mph=7, mpd=2)`
```

Below is the Matlab code that I want to emulate:

`[pks,locs] = findpeaks(data,'Npeaks',n)`

Comment: Give an output example you would like to see and specify why don't you like this four functions

Comment: I want to do audio spectrum analysis and use the peaks as features, however with these four functions, it will not give me a consistent number of features for each frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the exact function Matlab has, why not just use that function? If you have the rest of your data in Python, then you can just use the [module](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html) provided by Matlab.

```
import matlab.engine #import matlab engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab() #Start matlab engine

a = a = [(0.1*i)*(0.1*i-1)*(0.1*i-2) for i in range(50)] #Create some data with peaks
b = eng.findpeaks(matlab.double(a),'Npeaks',1) #Find 1 peak
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can all the functions from matlab be imported to Pyhthon?

Comment: Yes, you are basically running a Matlab session. You can also go the other way (using python in Matlab) by using `py.*cmd*`

Comment: That’s awesome, let me look into it. Thank you for the knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [findpeaks library](https://erdogant.github.io/findpeaks). Multiple methods are available for the detections of peaks and valleys in 1D-vectors and 2D-arrays (images).

```
pip install findpeaks
```

Lets create some peaks:

```
i = 10000
xs = np.linspace(0,3.7*np.pi,i)
X = (0.3*np.sin(xs) + np.sin(1.3 * xs) + 0.9 * np.sin(4.2 * xs) + 0.06 * 
np.random.randn(i))


# import library
from findpeaks import findpeaks

# Initialize
fp = findpeaks()

# Find the peaks (high/low)
results = fp.fit(X)

# Make plot
fp.plot()
```

[image: Peak data]

```
# Some of the results:
results['df']
```